# The curl is not zero?

Tags: electromagnetism

In Maxwell's equations, the curl of the electric field for a steady state processes (ie. No changing electric or magnetic field) zero. However,  if we take a curl along the wire for some distance and perpendicularly out from the wire and back to its original position (perpendicularly entering the wire), it is not zero for a resiative wire (non ideal wire) if we assume that there is no field outside the wire. This suggests that there could be electric field outside the wire. Is it? And if there indeed is, how to explain the energy conservation (because usually we just treat the energy to be all converted to thermal energy)?

Thank you

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to say between "However, if ..." and "... no field outside the wire." Could you explain it better?

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs, I think what the OP is actually describing is the line integral of the electric field along the rectangular path described.